# How to get the project flavors to get passed down to dependencies?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Say I have productFlavor "sdk" defined for the main project,

how can I pass the productFlavor (e.g. ./gradlew installAwesomeDebug, where Awesome is a "sdk" flavor type) to the dependencies so that in the dependencies can use magics such as using the right source folders?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do that. flavor is not (yet) supported in android-libraries

Comment: Yea, I ended up using sourceSets and project versions as workarounds for now.

Comment: You can add product flavors like which architectures should the apk contain or which apk should get invokedproductFlavors {
        demo {
            packageName "com.buildsystemexample.app.demo"
            versionName "1.0-demo"
        }
        full {
            packageName "com.buildsystemexample.app.full"
            versionName "1.0-full"
        }
    }

Comment: This will only apply to the app project but not the library projects.